# Python: I'm trying to snap vertices to the cursor while keeping the offset but I keep getting the context is incorrect error

Tags: modeling, python, mesh

Here is the code

```
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='VERT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_vertices_move(MESH_OT_extrude_verts_indiv={"mirror":False}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(-0, -0, -1.53096), "orient_axis_ortho":'X', "orient_type":'GLOBAL', "orient_matrix":((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, True), "mirror":False, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "view2d_edge_pan":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False, "use_automerge_and_split":False})
    bps.ops.mesh.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor(use_offset=True)
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

I'm given the error of RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_cursor.poll() failed, context is incorrect

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/270716/142292